# More empty Objects are added to the local storage after reload

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn about the use of localStorage in ReactJS. I was able to store the data inside an array; however, I am facing a small challenge, which is each time I reload the page, more empty objects are added to the localStorage.

I am not sure, what I am doing wrong in my code. If you have any comments, please feel free to leave me a comment:

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])

    const listFavorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myFavorites') || '[]');
    listFavorites.push(favorites)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("myFavorites", JSON.stringify(listFavorites));
       
    }, [listFavorites])
```

[image: console log showing empty objects]

Answer (score 0):

You are loading `listFavorites` from local storage on each render, you then push an empty array `listFavorites`, and `useEffect` is called to store this back to local storage.

Instead create a block of `useEffect` to load the favorites and store them to state on mount. You should also set the state with the loaded favorites:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const listFavorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myFavorites') || '[]')
  
  setFavorites(listFavorites) // replace empty favorites state with loaded favorites
}, [])
```

And another block to save the favorites to local stories when the change:

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("myFavorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
}, [favorites]) // you should track favorites changes
```